# Power Bi - Add calcuation to Group by in Advanced Editor

Tags: powerbi

I am working with PowerBi and somewhat new. I created a table by using the Group by function in the Power Bi Query Editor. In the group by, I am summing total duration in minutes by category. I want to get total duration in hours. Is it possible to divide by 60 to get the hour through the Advanced Editor. Below is the Advanced Editor code.

```
let
    Source = #"Data",
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"category"}, {{"Total Minutes", each List.Sum([duration_in_min]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([category] <> null))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: What is your raw duration data format? If it is in minutes, you can add a custom column  (before or after aggregation) and DIVIDE Minutes value by 60. If you can add some sample input data and your expected output from them, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you either calculate the total hours instead of total minutes by using

```
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"category"}, {{"Total Minutes", each List.Sum([duration_in_min]) / 60, type nullable number}}),
```

Or create a new column `Total Hours` so your query would be something like this:

```
let
    Source = Data,
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"category"}, {{"Total Minutes", each List.Sum([duration_in_min]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each ([category] <> null)),
    #"Added Total Hours" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Total Hours", each [Total Minutes]/60)
in
    #"Added Total Hours"
```